# Problem submitting struts form

Tags: java, struts

I have a form that has some indexed properties.

When i submit this form io get the following error message

```
javax.servlet.ServletException'(2009-09-16 13:14:29.814 GMT): BeanUtils.populate. ---
```

Any ideas what i should be looking for to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML form doesn't match your Action Form bean. For example, you might have a form control parameter not defined in your action form.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for the suggestion.
I only have 1 form value for now and that is referenced in my form.

In struts-config my form is of type org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm

Here is my entry in struts-config
<code>  <form-bean name="massUpdateTimeForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorForm">
        <form-property name="countryRegionTimes" type="com.fmr.whoswho.domain.MassUpdateTimeForm[]" />
     </form-bean></code>